# When I output the 2 numbers, the equation outputs the right solution but the for loop doesn't. How should I go about fixing this?

Tags: c++

I'm not entirely sure how to fix this code. I enter 7 and 9 as test numbers and I get 45 for the repetition one and I get 24 when I use the formula. How can I fix this problem?
 I've been working on the code for most of the day as a homework assignment and it's frustrating that one parts of it works but the other doesn't. I feel as though I'm using the for loop correctly but I could be wrong. I would really appreciate some assistance with this.

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <cmath>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        char response = 'y';
        while (response == 'y')
        {
            int N1;
            int N2;
            cout << "Please enter a number for N1 and N2: \n";
            cin >> N1 >> N2;
            while (N1 <= 1)
            {
                cout << "Number must be great than 1.\nPlease re-enter: ";
                cin >> N1;

            }
            while (N2 <= 1)
            {
                cout << "Number must be great than 1.\nPlease re-enter: ";
                cin >> N2;
            }
            while (N2 <= N1)
            {
                cout << "Number must be great than 1.\nPlease re-enter both nubers: ";
                cin >> N1 >> N2;
            }
            int sum1 = 0;
            int sum2 = 0;
            for (int N1 = 0; N1 <= N2; N1++) // not sure how to fix this
            {
                sum1 = sum1 + N1;
            }
            cout << "Using summation and repetition the sum of the values " << N1 << " and " << N2 <<    " is " << sum1 << ".\n";
            sum2 = ((N2*(N2 + 1)) / 2 )- (N1 - 1)*((N1 - 1) + 1) / (2);
            cout << "\nUsing the formula, N2(N2+1))/2 - (N1-1)((N1 - 1) + 1) / 2, the sum of the values " << N1 << " and " << N2 << " are "
                << sum2 << ".\n";
                cout << "\nWould you like to run the program again? \n"
                << "Enter y for yes or n for no: ";
            cin >> response;
        }
        return 0;


    }
```

Comment: Which part works, and which doesn't? What are you trying to do?

Comment: When N2 <= N1, you should tell the user that the second number has to be greater than the first number. Also, it's "greater than", not "great than".

Comment: The for loop is the part that isn't working. I input say 7 for N1, when it gets to the for loop instead of starting at 7 and adding all the way up to N2. It starts at 0 and counts up to N2.

Comment: `for (int i = N1; i <= N2; i++) sum1 = sum1 + i;`

Comment: halex that's the closest I've been all day but they still aren't the same answer.

Comment: Oh yes I've figured it out. Thank you.

Comment: @Jim n(n+1) will always be even when n is an integer, so shouldn't div by 2 or 2.0 produce the same answer?